# How to see complete text below your collapsed toolbar

Tags: android, textview, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

When I am scrolling my textview upward,the amount of text shown depends when the toolbar where it collpased, and the text below is not visible ie: it is not scrolling anymore.
Here is my code of activity_main.xml:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:background="@drawable/default_image"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:title="@string/toolbartitle"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                >
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frag"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/goto_frag"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="goto Fragment" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When I will click on this button a fragment will be loaded into this framelayout.
Here is the code of my fragment activity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".Fragment1">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:elevation="5dp">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:text="@string/apptext"
                    android:textSize="18sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should probably wrap your `Fragment` inside a `NestedScrollView` layout. Currently it is the other way around. Also add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` attribute to your `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Pl share some of the screenshots!

Comment: @Radhey I dont have enough reputations to embed screen shots.

Comment: Save your images in imgur.com and text url here.

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez It didnt worked(both). suggest something else.

Comment: @Radhey https://imgur.com/a/DPMMG.

Comment: change `FrameLayout` `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez nothing change. I have tried it before.

Comment: [Inline Link](http://paste.ofcode.org)  /LAD8s4ZRmUcBX8CNachGSx , append that string to view code stuff. try it and do let me know.

Comment: @Radhey this link is an empty paste bin sort of, don't know what to do with it.

Comment: append  /LAD8s4ZRmUcBX8CNachGSx in url inside address bar after click on that inline link (paste.ofcode.org/LAD8s4ZRmUcBX8CNachGSx)

Comment: @Radhey prompted lots of errors.